# how to concatenate large integers in Java?

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I am trying to write a simple program which would generate randomly 3 integers, then put them in array and then concatenate them into a single sequence of integers, but it throws an error

here is the code:

```
int [] kol=new int[3];

for(int j=0;j<3;j++) {
    kol[j]=(int)Math.round(Math.random() * 89999) + 10000;              
    System.out.print(kol[j] +"\n" );                
}

String ma=kol[0]+","+kol[1]+","+kol[2]+";";
System.out.println(ma);
```

I also tried:

```
int b = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(kol[0]) + Integer.toString(kol[1]) +
    Integer.toString(kol[2]));
System.out.println(b);
```

but same error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input 
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
string: "715534907077099"
```

Comment: Use `BigInteger`?

Comment: Your trying to cast a big value that the int can't take, try to use `BigInteger` as @MoritzPetersen suggested.

Comment: i tried  int b = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(kol[0]) + Integer.toString(kol[1])+ Integer.toString(kol[2]));
    tesa=tesa.add(BigInteger.valueOf(b)); 
    
    System.out.println(tesa);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java, `int` type is a 32-bit signed value, of which the maximum value is 2147483647(2^31-1).
Obviously your value "715534907077099" is much bigger than Integer.MAX_VALUE. If it's still less than Long.MAX_VALUE, `int n = Long.parseLong(strValue)` will work.

But if you don't want to have a up limit, use `BigInteger` instead:

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(Integer.toString(kol[0]) + Integer.toString(kol[1]) +
    Integer.toString  (kol[2]));
System.out.println(bi);
```

[image: It seem that I need to upload a pic to prove my code, according to the comments...]

Comment: i tried the above code ,still the same exception, can it be that even the BigInteger has a limit ?

Comment: It seems that I make some spell mistake in the code above. I've correct it. Try again. @user2557930

Comment: i myself corrected the spelling, that was not the issue, you can try compile it yourself, it gives same exception

Comment: Are you sure you've got the same exception. It seems that I have to upload a pic to prove my code. Ha.

Answer (score 6):

Integer range is not enough to have your large values.

```
int MAX_VALUE = 2147483647
int MIN_VALUE = -2147483648
```

So instead use [java.math.BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/class-use/BigInteger.html) for the same